# Two textviews one on left and one on the right side

Tags: android, textview

I trying to make two textviews on same line. One on the left and one on the right. Tried with RelativeLayout with `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` but seems not to work. How can I do this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/restaurants_buttons">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ColPhoto"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
/>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/ColName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text=""
        />
        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#CCCCCC" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/ColPrice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text=""
        />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/ColWeight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text=""
        />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I try to align `ColPrice` and `ColWeight`. Also if it's possible with `LinearLayout`.

Comment: what exactly you need? can you show a screenshot?

Comment: have u any design and why <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ColPhoto"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
/>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to wrap those TextViews in a LinearLayout.
Like this:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ColPhoto"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ColName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#CCCCCC" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ColPrice"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ColWeight"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this simple code.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/restaurants_buttons">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="27dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ColPhoto"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ColName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="#CCCCCC" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ColPrice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="ColPrice" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ColWeight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="ColWeight" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```